# iOS Twitter integration testing

Tags: objective-c, ios, twitter

When adding twitter integration into my iOS app, is there an appropriate way to test sending tweets?  What I mean is, should I create a dummy twitter account for the sole purpose of testing?  Or is there a way to test the ability to Tweet without filling twitter with useless testing tweets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need, because your are using the in-app twitter. When you run it in the simulator it shows a error popup window, but in the iphone it ask for accounts which means is working.

The only on problem if you are using features as photo share, location share, etc.. But actually you just need to check the code. I recommend this page to be shure with the code:
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-5-and-the-twitter-framework-first-steps/

There is also another tutorial more advanced for twitter. Hope it helps..

Comment: That's a great tutorial.  I guess it makes sense that once I see the twitter window I know my code works.  Thanks!